# How can I download gedit from Windows and install it from a pendrive?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, but have not been able to connect with wifi (it works fine when using Windows). Is there any way to download gedit from Windows, then install it on Ubuntu using a pendrive?

Comment: Gedit comes pre-installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh! I hadn't noticed that. But if want to install any other software, will the above process work?

Comment: Read Marc's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most software is available as a `.deb` package. You could download that, save it somewhere Ubuntu could find it, and use that to install the application. However, if there are any dependencies not already installed or included in the `.deb`, then you'll have trouble.

A better plan is to fix the WiFi. You might need internet access to do that, but surely you can plug into Ethernet long enough to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Gedit comes with Ubuntu out of the box. Just open a terminal with `ctrl + shift + t` and type `Gedit`